# Backup Plus Portable Drive stop working

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

The issue started when I unplogged the drive from one of my computers without safely remove it, then I connect the device to my other computer and it does't work, I attached some images of the screen when I am on disk management: [disk management image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijpaV.png), [disk management error when I tried to initialize the drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBiYh.png), also the drive appears on disk drives section and storage controllers section but not in "this pc" window, just appear C: drive there.

I also tried to install Paragon Driver for Windows software cause I look into some youtube videos and they fixed not dectection that way but it doesn't work for me.

device information: backup plus portable drive model:SRD00F1

both computers have windows 10 pro,

1st one (motherboard: intel DH61CR):

- 16 gb ram
- intel core i5 3350p 3.10ghz
- nvidia geforce gtx 750ti

2nd (Aspire E 15):

- intel core i5 6200U 2.3Ghz
- 8gb ram ddr4
- nvdia geforce 940mx 2gb

Comment: What happens when you plug the drive into your other computers? Same thing?

Comment: I just have two computers, I was using the drive all the morning with my first computer then I remove it unsafely and connect it to my second computer, it doesn't work in this last one, I unplugged from the second and connect it again to the first one, and this time doesn't work

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the controller in the drive itself if the problem is occurring on two computers. It wouldn't hurt to try it on a friend's computer. Also, I'd wager neglecting to "safely eject" the drive didn't cause the problem.

Comment: I need to solve this today, I have no friends near from me

Comment: If you need to solve this very quickly, and you need to keep the data on the external drive safe, whatever the cost, the best thing to do will be to remove the actual hard drive from the external bay it is housed inside, connect it to your computer using a different means, and copying the data off of it. This itself is a risky move and is likely to permanently destroy the external case. If the drive is OK, it'll survive the ordeal.

Comment: Also, while I get that computer problems are frustrating and often interfere with what we'd rather be doing, we on SU cannot simply wave a magic wand and make things better. You've already tried the things we'd usually suggest in this situation, which means your issue is more complicated or more serious. Most likely more serious. If you must have this fixed today I recommend seeking out professional assistance from a local technology shop.

Comment: Boot up your favorite Linux LiveCD and see if it is visible there.  Linux is more forgiving about some things like this.

Comment: I will be trying with linux, but I know anything about this OS

Comment: @KennyAmaro If you use the command `dmesg` in a Linux terminal shortly after plugging in the drive, it will show you the log of the kernel (the software that manages hardware).  There might be some lines towards the end/bottom with an error message you can research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Enclosure is Dead, Extract Hard Drive

Sounds like your USB enclosure died.  The hard drive inside might still be okay though!

There are probably some screws you can unscrew to disassemble the enclosure (they may be hidden underneath stickers.)

As [music2myear](https://superuser.com/users/74026) said, this will likely **permanently destroy** the enclosure, but it's not working anyway.

---

I've had a USB enclosure fail before, and I was able to extract the still-working hard drive for the data.

Comment: I remove the usb enclosure and I connect it directly to the pc but it didn't work, was recognizing it at least with the enclosure but directly to the pc it didn't ... I connect both cables by the way sata and data

Comment: another thing, is if the enclosure is not working, why the pc recognize the hardware?... do you look at the images I upload? it says, unknow, not initialized...

Comment: @KennyAmaro Sorry to hear plugging it directly in didn't work.  Hardware doesn't always fail completely, nor gracefully.  Also, software isn't always programed properly to handle such failures.  It's possible that the bad drive didn't report accurate info, so the disk manager defaulted to "uninitialized", even though it didn't really know that.